# How would I parse a result and insert it into a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently attempting to make a hangman game, whereby you can choose the number of letters in a word.

```py
hLetters = int(input("How many letters? (4-16)\n"))

  def word(letters):
    if letters == 4:
      random.choice(list4)
    if letters == 5:
      random.choice(list5)
    # etc, etc

word(hLetters)
```

Obviously, this is inefficient - is there a method of getting the value of hLetters to be placed after "list", so that it automatically picks "list4" when the input is 4, or "list8" when the input is 8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could place all you lists in a dictionary -

```
words_lists = {4 : list4, 5: list5}
```

And choose randomly from this dict values -

```
random.choice(words_lists[letters])
```

Comment: A list would be slightly more efficient both in storage and access speed. `[*((None,) * 4), list4, list5, ...]` lets you use `words_list[letters]` without subtraction, but `[list4, list5, ...]` would work fine too provided you subtract 4 from `letters` to make it a valid index.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a list of list for this

```
letter = 4 
listoflist=[list4,list5,list6,..list16]
print(random.choice(listoflist[letter-4]))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a list of lists. Just like you have a list for multiple letters, instead of referring them as letter1, letter2, make a lists of you multiple lists

```
 outer_list = [list1, list2, ...]
```

and then

```
random.choice(outer_list[letter - 1])
```

Comment: Think you're missing a part in the second block. `random.choice(outer_list[letter-1])`, other then that a nice solution :)